# scipy.optimize.minimize "ValueError:The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, scipy

Sample Code:  https://pastebin.com/L8qV1eWQ

Link to PDF/Image of the code: https://imgur.com/tiPcB8M

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math as m
import random

#Inputs:
## X = A 100x6 array of 600 organized variables.
def func(X):
    x = 0
    for i in range(0,100):
        for j in range(0,6):
            x = x = X[i][j]
    return -1.0*x

#Inputs:
## a = the A matrix constructed below
## d = the d array constructed below
#Outputs:
# res - result of optimization
def Optimize(a,c,d):
    ###Constraints###    
    cons = list()
    for i in range(0,100):
        cons.append(
                {'type' : 'ineq',
                 'fun'  : lambda X : np.array([ X[i][0]+X[i][1]+
                            X[i][2]+X[i][3]+X[i][4]+X[i][5]-d ]),
                 'jac'  : lambda X : np.ones(6) })
    for j in range(0,6):
        cons.append(
                {'type' : 'ineq',
                 'fun'  : lambda X : np.array([ 
                     X[0][j]+ X[1][j]+ X[2][j]+ X[3][j]+ X[4][j]+ 
                     X[5][j]+ X[6][j]+ X[7][j]+ X[8][j]+ X[9][j]+
                     X[10][j]+X[11][j]+X[12][j]+X[13][j]+X[14][j]+X[15][j]+
                     X[16][j]+X[17][j]+X[18][j]+X[19][j]+
                     X[20][j]+X[21][j]+X[22][j]+X[23][j]+X[24][j]+X[25][j]+
                     X[26][j]+X[27][j]+X[28][j]+X[29][j]+
                     X[30][j]+X[31][j]+X[32][j]+X[33][j]+X[34][j]+X[35][j]+
                     X[36][j]+X[37][j]+X[38][j]+X[39][j]+
                     X[40][j]+X[41][j]+X[42][j]+X[43][j]+X[44][j]+X[45][j]+
                     X[46][j]+X[47][j]+X[48][j]+X[49][j]+
                     X[50][j]+X[51][j]+X[52][j]+X[53][j]+X[54][j]+X[55][j]+
                     X[56][j]+X[57][j]+X[58][j]+X[59][j]+
                     X[60][j]+X[61][j]+X[62][j]+X[63][j]+X[64][j]+X[65][j]+
                     X[66][j]+X[67][j]+X[68][j]+X[69][j]+
                     X[70][j]+X[71][j]+X[72][j]+X[73][j]+X[74][j]+X[75][j]+
                     X[76][j]+X[77][j]+X[78][j]+X[79][j]+
                     X[80][j]+X[81][j]+X[82][j]+X[83][j]+X[84][j]+X[85][j]+
                     X[86][j]+X[87][j]+X[88][j]+X[89][j]+
                     X[90][j]+X[91][j]+X[92][j]+X[93][j]+X[94][j]+X[95][j]+
                     X[96][j]+X[97][j]+X[98][j]+X[99][j]
                     -c]),
                 'jac'  : lambda X : np.ones(100)})

    bnds = list()
    for i in range(0,100):
        for j in range(0,6):
            bnds.append((0,A[i][j]))

    res = minimize(func, np.zeros(shape=(100,6)), jac=np.ones(600), bounds = 
          bnds, constraints=cons, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True})


    return res

##Create sample matrix and arrays of values##
A = np.zeros(shape=(100,6))
def p1(A,temp):
    for i in range(0,temp.size):
        j = int(random.uniform(0, 6))
        A[i][j] = temp[i]
    return A
numbers = np.array([4*(m.ceil(0.05*m.e**(0.08*i))) for i in range(0,100)])
A = p1(A,numbers)

d = [[] for i in range(0,100)]
for i in range(0,100):
    d[i] = np.hstack(np.random.poisson(lam=(m.ceil(0.05*m.e**(0.08*i))), 
    size=(1)))

Optimize(A,370,d)
```

I am working on a project to replicate the results of a 2017 paper.
Part of the paper involves solving a specific optimization problem called the
max-flow problem. 
I have constructed a simple example of sufficient scale to replicate the problem
I am having.  I am new to using the optimization algorithms in python.

The question seems to be a linear optimization problem with normal inequality 
constraints along the sum of each row, and the sum of each column and box constraints or bounds on each specific element.

So I use the constraint argument for the row sum and column sum constraints
then I used the bounds argument to bound each of the individual matrix elements.

The error I am getting seems to be coming from the jacobian.
Since my problem is given in the form of a matrix, I am assuming that each element of the matrix is its own variable and is linear, the matrix is 100 x 6, so 600 linear variables,  Hence the gradient would be a vector of ones of length 600

It seems the algorithm does not accept my jacobian and attempts to calculate its own but then runs into a value error.  Though I could be wrong.

I hope this is enough information to help me understand the fix.

Comment: Reread the docs first, especially this part: ```jac : bool or callable, optional```. Yours is none of that. (i also would never consider using scipy's minimize for some max-flow problem; if it's really this kind of problem; either use scipy's linprog or networkx' algorithms / or graph-tools in *this* case)

Comment: I also do think your math does not make much sense. If the jacobian is constant (and nonzero), those algorithms will probably never converge.

Comment: What do you mean the math does not make sense?  The jacobian calculation?  Its a maximization problem with upper bounds on each of the variables.   I will try linprog, Thanks.

Comment: I am getting success with the linprog library.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: FYI: It looks like you have a mistake in the line `x = x = X[i][j]` in  `func`.  Should that second `=` be `+`?

Comment: The `minimize` code does not handle `x` being a matrix.  To quote from the description of the `x` argument of `func` in the docstring: "The optimizing argument, ``x``, is a 1-D array of points".  You'll have to flatten `X` into a 1-D array.